# Calculate count of all the elements in nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dictionary

I have list of lists and would like to create data frame with count of all unique elements. Here is my test data:

```
test = [["P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P1", "P1", "P3"],
        ["P1", "P1", "P1"],
        ["P1", "P1", "P1", "P2"],
        ["P4"],
        ["P1", "P4", "P2"],
        ["P1", "P1", "P1"]]
```

I can do something like this using `Counter` with `for` loop as:

```
from collections import Counter
for item in test:
     print(Counter(item))
```

But how can I have result of this loop summed up into new data frame ?

Expected output as data frame:

```
P1 P2 P3 P4
15 4  1  2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

test = [["P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P1", "P1", "P3"],
        ["P1", "P1", "P1"],
        ["P1", "P1", "P1", "P2"],
        ["P4"],
        ["P1", "P4", "P2"],
        ["P1", "P1", "P1"]]

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(test))

for k, v in c.items():
    print(k, v)

# P1 15
# P2 4
# P3 1
# P4 2
```

For output as dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index').transpose()

#    P1 P2 P3 P4
# 0  15  4  1  2
```

Comment: There already is functionality to handle imports like you do. It is `from itertools import chain.from_iterable as concat`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Actually not quite, `from itertools import chain as concat` would be possible though and I agree that the one liner they current have is nasty, but otherwise decent answer (I made an edit, hope it's ok)

Comment: You don't need a loop, to transform it into a DataFrame: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index').transpose()` or even shorter:
`pd.DataFrame(c, index=[0])`

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well originally they were re-naming `itertools.chain.from_iterable ` , which I've always thought is too long. Anyway I think they were referring to http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.concat

Answer (score 5):

In terms of better performance, you should be either using:

- [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) as:

  ```
  >>> from collections import Counter
  >>> from itertools import chain

  >>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(test))
  Counter({'P1': 15, 'P2': 4, 'P4': 2, 'P3': 1})
  ```
- OR, yo should be using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with *list comprehension* *(requires one less import of `itertools` with same performance)* as:

  ```
  >>> from collections import Counter

  >>> Counter([x for a in test for x in a])
  Counter({'P1': 15, 'P2': 4, 'P4': 2, 'P3': 1})
  ```

Keep reading for more alternative solutions and the performance comparison. *(skip otherwise)*

---

***Approach 1***: **Concatenate your sublists to create the single `list` and find the count using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)**.

- **Solution 1**: Concatenate list using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and find the count using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as:

  ```
  test = [
      ["P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P1", "P1", "P3"],
      ["P1", "P1", "P1"],
      ["P1", "P1", "P1", "P2"],
      ["P4"],
      ["P1", "P4", "P2"],
      ["P1", "P1", "P1"]
  ]

  from itertools import chain 
  from collections import Counter

  my_counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(test))
  ```
- **Solution 2**: Combine list using *list comprehension* as:

  ```
  from collections import Counter

  my_counter = Counter([x for a in my_list for x in a])
  ```
- **Solution 3**: Concatenate list using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

  ```
  from collections import Counter

  my_counter = Counter(sum(test, []))
  ```

---

***Approach 2:*** **Calculate count of elements in each sublist using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) the `Counter` objects** in the list.

- **Solution 4**: Count objects of each sublist using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as:

  ```
  from collections import Counter

  my_counter = sum(map(Counter, test), Counter())
  ```
- **Solution 5**: Count objects of each sublist using *list comprehension* as:

  ```
  from collections import Counter

  my_counter = sum([Counter(t) for t in test], Counter())
  ```

In all the solutions above, `my_counter` will hold the value:

```
>>> my_counter
Counter({'P1': 15, 'P2': 4, 'P4': 2, 'P3': 1})
```

---

## Performance Comparison

Below is the `timeit` comparison on Python 3 for the list of 1000 sublist and 100 elements in each sublist:

1. Fastest using `chain.from_iterable` *(17.1 msec)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "from collections import Counter; from itertools import chain; my_list = [list(range(100)) for i in range(1000)]" "Counter(chain.from_iterable(my_list))"
   100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 msec per loop
   ```
2. Second on the list is using *list comprehension* to combine the list and then do the `Count` (similar result as above but without the additional import of `itertools`) *(18.36 msec)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "from collections import Counter; my_list = [list(range(100)) for i in range(1000)]" "Counter([x for a in my_list for x in a])"
   100 loops, best of 3: 18.36 msec per loop
   ```
3. Third in terms of performance is using `Counter` on sublists within *list comprehension* : *(162 msec)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "from collections import Counter; my_list = [list(range(100)) for i in range(1000)]" "sum([Counter(t) for t in my_list], Counter())"
   10 loops, best of 3: 162 msec per loop
   ```
4. Fourth on the list is via using `Counter` with `map` (results are quite similar to the one using *list comprehension* above) *(176 msec)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "from collections import Counter; my_list = [list(range(100)) for i in range(1000)]" "sum(map(Counter, my_list), Counter())"
   10 loops, best of 3: 176 msec per loop
   ```
5. Solution using `sum` to concatenate the list is too slow *(526 msec)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "from collections import Counter; my_list = [list(range(100)) for i in range(1000)]" "Counter(sum(my_list, []))"
   10 loops, best of 3: 526 msec per loop
   ```

Comment: Yeah, but then it won't be summing up the `Counter` but running single Counter on the combined list. However I think I should mention this one too in the answer *(nice way to skip import of `itertools` with same performance)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain

>>> out = [(k,len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(sorted(chain(*test)))]
>>> out
>>> [('P1', 15), ('P2', 4), ('P3', 1), ('P4', 2)]
```

Convert it to dict like:

```
>>> dict(out)
>>> {'P2': 4, 'P3': 1, 'P1': 15, 'P4': 2}
```

To convert it to dataframe use

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(out), index=[0])
   P1  P2  P3  P4
0  15   4   1   2
```

Answer (score 0):

The function "set" keeps only the unique elements in a list. Thus, using "len(set(mylinst))", you get the number of unique elements in your list. Then, you only have to iterate over it.

```
dict_nb_item = {}
i = 0
for test_item in test:
    dict_nb_item[i] = len(set(test_item))
    i += 1
print(dict_nb_item)
```

Comment: How does this produce the result the OP is after?

Comment: This one is outputting `{0: 3, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 1}` (Python-3) which is hardy what the OP is looking for.